# LLVM asserts "Resolving symbol with incorrect flags"

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm following the example of Kaleidoscope to write a minimum IR file interpreter. It takes one command line argument, which is a path to .ll file, and executes the `main` function in the file. But when I tested it on an IR file, it failed with:

> Assertion failed: (KV.second.getFlags() & ~WeakFlags) == (I->second & ~WeakFlags) && "Resolving symbol with incorrect flags", file <path>\llvm\lib\ExecutionEngine\Orc\Core.cpp, line 2775

Considering the simplicity of my code (which only has 63 lines), I can't figure out what's wrong in it. Please help !!!

### Full Source Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <llvm/IR/DataLayout.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>

#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>

#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>

#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/CompileUtils.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Core.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ExecutionUtils.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ExecutorProcessControl.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/IRCompileLayer.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/JITTargetMachineBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/RTDyldObjectLinkingLayer.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/SectionMemoryManager.h>

using namespace llvm;

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  InitializeNativeTarget();
  InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
  InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();

  orc::ThreadSafeContext tsctx(std::make_unique<LLVMContext>());

  SMDiagnostic error;
  auto mod = parseIRFile(argv[1], error, *tsctx.getContext());

  auto epc = orc::SelfExecutorProcessControl::Create();
  cantFail(epc.takeError());

  orc::ExecutionSession es(std::move(*epc));

  auto triple = es.getExecutorProcessControl().getTargetTriple();
  orc::JITTargetMachineBuilder jtmb(triple);

  auto dl = jtmb.getDefaultDataLayoutForTarget();
  cantFail(dl.takeError());

  orc::RTDyldObjectLinkingLayer ol(
    es, []() { return std::make_unique<SectionMemoryManager>(); });
  orc::IRCompileLayer cl(
    es, ol, std::make_unique<orc::ConcurrentIRCompiler>(std::move(jtmb)));

  auto& jd = es.createBareJITDylib("jd");
  jd.addGenerator(
    cantFail(orc::DynamicLibrarySearchGenerator::GetForCurrentProcess(
      dl->getGlobalPrefix())));

  cantFail(cl.add(jd, orc::ThreadSafeModule(std::move(mod), tsctx)));

  orc::MangleAndInterner mangle(es, *dl);
  auto f = es.lookup({ &jd }, mangle("main"));
  cantFail(f.takeError());

  return reinterpret_cast<int (*)()>(f->getAddress())();
}
```

### Test .ll file

```
; ModuleID = 'sum.ll'
source_filename = "sum.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.29.30133"

%struct._iobuf = type { i8* }
%struct.__crt_locale_pointers = type { %struct.__crt_locale_data*, %struct.__crt_multibyte_data* }
%struct.__crt_locale_data = type opaque
%struct.__crt_multibyte_data = type opaque

$scanf = comdat any

$__local_stdio_scanf_options = comdat any

$"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@" = comdat any

@"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@" = linkonce_odr dso_local unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"%d\00", comdat, align 1
@__local_stdio_scanf_options._OptionsStorage = internal global i64 0, align 8

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = bitcast i32* %1 to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %2) #6
  %3 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %4 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %5 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %6 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %7 = add nsw i32 %6, %4
  %8 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %9 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %10 = add nsw i32 %7, %9
  %11 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %12 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %13 = add nsw i32 %10, %12
  %14 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %15 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %16 = add nsw i32 %13, %15
  %17 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %18 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %19 = add nsw i32 %16, %18
  %20 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %21 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %22 = add nsw i32 %19, %21
  %23 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %24 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %25 = add nsw i32 %22, %24
  %26 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %27 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %28 = add nsw i32 %25, %27
  %29 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @"??_C@_02DPKJAMEF@?$CFd?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0), i32* nonnull %1)
  %30 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %31 = add nsw i32 %28, %30
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %2) #6
  ret i32 %31
}

; Function Attrs: argmemonly mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn
declare void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 immarg, i8* nocapture) #1

; Function Attrs: inlinehint nobuiltin nounwind uwtable
define linkonce_odr dso_local i32 @scanf(i8* %0, ...) local_unnamed_addr #2 comdat {
  %2 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %3 = bitcast i8** %2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 8, i8* nonnull %3) #6
  call void @llvm.va_start(i8* nonnull %3)
  %4 = load i8*, i8** %2, align 8, !tbaa !8
  %5 = call %struct._iobuf* @__acrt_iob_func(i32 0) #6
  %6 = call i64* @__local_stdio_scanf_options() #6
  %7 = load i64, i64* %6, align 8, !tbaa !10
  %8 = call i32 @__stdio_common_vfscanf(i64 %7, %struct._iobuf* %5, i8* %0, %struct.__crt_locale_pointers* null, i8* %4) #6
  call void @llvm.va_end(i8* nonnull %3)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 8, i8* nonnull %3) #6
  ret i32 %8
}

; Function Attrs: argmemonly mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn
declare void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 immarg, i8* nocapture) #1

; Function Attrs: mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn
declare void @llvm.va_start(i8*) #3

; Function Attrs: mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn
declare void @llvm.va_end(i8*) #3

declare dso_local %struct._iobuf* @__acrt_iob_func(i32) local_unnamed_addr #4

declare dso_local i32 @__stdio_common_vfscanf(i64, %struct._iobuf*, i8*, %struct.__crt_locale_pointers*, i8*) local_unnamed_addr #4

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define linkonce_odr dso_local i64* @__local_stdio_scanf_options() local_unnamed_addr #5 comdat {
  ret i64* @__local_stdio_scanf_options._OptionsStorage
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable "frame-pointer"="none" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #1 = { argmemonly mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn }
attributes #2 = { inlinehint nobuiltin nounwind uwtable "frame-pointer"="none" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #3 = { mustprogress nofree nosync nounwind willreturn }
attributes #4 = { "frame-pointer"="none" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #5 = { noinline nounwind uwtable "frame-pointer"="none" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #6 = { nounwind }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1, !2}
!llvm.ident = !{!3}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 2}
!1 = !{i32 7, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!2 = !{i32 7, !"uwtable", i32 1}
!3 = !{!"clang version 13.0.1"}
!4 = !{!5, !5, i64 0}
!5 = !{!"int", !6, i64 0}
!6 = !{!"omnipotent char", !7, i64 0}
!7 = !{!"Simple C/C++ TBAA"}
!8 = !{!9, !9, i64 0}
!9 = !{!"any pointer", !6, i64 0}
!10 = !{!11, !11, i64 0}
!11 = !{!"long long", !6, i64 0}
```

Which is compiled from:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  int n, sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum += n;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that **THERE IS NOTHING WRONG WITH MY CODE!**

I compile and test the same code in Linux environment (WSL2), and everything works fine. I'm pretty sure that this is somewhat compatibility problem between Linux and Windows.

Maybe this is a bug of LLVM?